# Найти количество целочисленных координат принадлежащих отрезку

Tags: python

Надо в задаче определить сколько всего целочисленных координат принадлнжат данному отрезку.

На вход идут координаты концов отрезков x1,y1,x2,y2.
На выход надо вывести количество точек отрезка, имеющих целочисленные координаты.

Ввод: 1 0 5 0

Вывод: 5

```
x1, y1, x2, y2 = map(int, input().split())
if x1 < x2:
    a = x2 - x1
else:
    a = x1 - x2
if y1 < y2:
    b = y2 - y1
else:
    b = y1 - y2
from math import gcd
print(gsd(a, b)+1)
```

Comment: Чем помочь-то -  gcd правильно написать?

Comment: Нет, это описка, просто тестируящая система пишет на мой код 0 тестов из 36

Comment: Значит, что-то неправильно или не так, как ожидает система, читаете или выводите

Answer (score 0):

Что-то невидно никаких потуг с вашей стороны к решению задач вами самостоятельно. Понятно почему "0 тестов из 36". Но непонятно, причем тут gcd. Вообще ничего. За такое на этом форуме банят.

Но, учитывая, что вы как-бы новичек, а меня тут призывают быть терпимее к двоечникам и лентяям, даю вам "решение". А уж как его уложить в вашу тестовую систему -  думайте сами.

```
for x in range(x1,x2+1):
    for y in range (y1,y2+1):
        if abs((y1 - y2) * x + (x2 - x1) * y + (x1 * y2 - x2 * y1)) /(((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)**0.5) ==0 :
            print(x,y)
```

Comment: `причем тут gcd`  дык математика такую формулу даёт.

Comment: Так gcd возвращает единственное число. Мало того, что точек может быть много, так каждая их них задается парой координат. И вопрос "причем тут gcd" возникает снова.

Comment: Прошу прощения, но поскольку, кроме принципиального замечания @MBo , что смысл этого кода вообще не ясен ввиду явной его неэффективности. В коде ошибки (`range(x1+1,x2)` и `range (y1+1,y2)`), код не рабочий. Поэтому - минус.

Comment: @passant Требуется вывести `количество точек отрезка, имеющих целочисленные координаты.`, а не сами эти точки. У автора приведён правильный код, если исправить `gsd`

Comment: @Serge3leo, Спасибо, вчера ночью немного недоглядел. Код подправлен, теперь он рабочий полностью. Что касается ответа  -  я привел код, выводящий все требуемые точки. Получить из них количество таких  точек -  это добавить единственный оператор, что и имелось ввиду под   "как его уложить в вашу тестовую систему - думайте сами". Использовании в качестве ответа готовой функции -  мало что даст с точки зрения изучения языка. Впрочем, если цель не изучение, а просто сдача тестов -  тогда можно и math.gcd.